# Cufflinks Candlestick Chart Error in Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, google-colaboratory, cufflinks

I am a newbie in Google Colab. I just wanna create a candlestick chart but I saw errors everytime I have tried. The code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
df_twtr = yf.download('TWTR',
start='2018-01-01', end='2018-12-31', progress=False, auto_adjust=True)
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode 
init_notebook_mode()
qf = cf.QuantFig(df_twtr, title="Twitter's Stock Price", legend='top', name='TWTR')
qf.add_volume()
qf.add_sma(periods=20, column='Close', color='red')
qf.add_ema(periods=20, color='green')
qf.iplot()
```

I can create the plot in JupyterLab , it works well. But gives error in Colab. How can I solve that problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Colab is sharable, so you need to import the chart_studio library and set the APIkey. `import chart_studio;chart_studio.tools.set_credentials_file(username='your account', api_key='your api key')`

Comment: [https://plotly.com/python/getting-started-with-chart-studio/](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started-with-chart-studio/)

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. have a nice day :)

Comment: @r-beginners today, i added your extra code to my colab notebook , but ı cant see the plot. colab is not showing the plot, although vscode and jupyter shows it. what can i do

Comment: Colab requires Yahoo Finance and chart_studio to be installed. Have you done this?